# What is the impact of (slow) wireless charging vs (slow) wired charging on the phone battery?

Tags: battery, charging

Can someone give me some feedback related to BATTERY LIFE in terms of wired vs wireless charging?

I already know that fast charging CAN reduce battery life. Do we have any info on wireless charging? Since it's an inductive charging, some part of it's energy it's released as heat (not used for charging) and I think it SHOULD affect the battery.

The wireless charger I bought is a Wireless Qi Fast Charge Standing Samsung EP-N5100 with fans incorporated to reduce the heating. (Yeah, I use it on a compatible Samsung smartphone)

I made the mistake to have the fast charge active for some time (didn't know it was active by default), but I only charge it from 40 to 80 so I hope no less damage has been done. Since I plan to keep the phone for a while (I doubt I'll switch in 2 years), I want to try and be careful with the battery.